# Getting Certain values from an AJAX return JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am trying to retrieve certain values in a JSON object retrieved from AJAX.

Using `console.log()`, I was able to view these:

```
0: Object
   title: "First post"
   body: "This is a post"
   id: 1
   userId: 27
.
.
.
100: //same format of data as object 0
```

Now I want to try storing the whole JSON object above so that I can use the `userId` and match it with another list of data to find the user who made the post. Problem is, I can't store it to a global variable. Here is my jscript snippet:

```
var postJson; //global variable

---somewhere in a function---
$.ajax({
      url: root + '/posts',
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(response){
      postJson = response;
        console.log(response);                 
          }
      });
```

I also tried doing `postJson = $.ajax` but nothing happened and `postJson` continues to be undefined.

Comment: You might be trying to use `postJson` variable, before your ajax response has been received. I think if you console it inside the `success` handler, you would print the expected json object.

Comment: What is the error message when you try to store it to the global variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: no error message however when I use console.log(postJson) outside the success, it shows up as "undefined" in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.ajax is async function, you need to use callback or do all the code in success function

```
var postJson; //global variable

function doSomething(r){
    //r is here
}

---somewhere in a function---
$.ajax({
      url: root + '/posts',
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(response){
          postJson = response;

          //do something with postJson or call function doSomething(response)     
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function doSomething(r){
    //r is here
}

---somewhere in a function---
$.ajax({
      url: root + '/posts',
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(response){
      doSomething(response);
          //do something with postJson or call function doSomething(response)     
      }
});
```

You can do directly via calling function from response no need to declare variable. Hope it will also helps you